# Mongo DB schema designing problem

Tags: c#, mongodb, schema-design

I m designing a mongo db schema for a site like stackoverflow. There are questions and users.
Users can add questions to their favorite list and they can search for a question within the favorite list.

I have 2 collections, as Users and Questions. Problem is how to store favorites. There are 2 options

1. Store a list of favorite question Id s with a user
2. Store a list of user ids (of the users who added this question to their favorites), with the question.

Which approach should I take ? Remember I need to search favorites of a user too.

For an estimate of db/record sizes, assume number of questions, users db operations that the stackoverflow has

For more info;

This app is an asp.net mvc written in c# and hope to use Lucene.NET for search

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you designing site like SO and want to achieve same performance you for sure need denormalize your data. So, i suggest to store user favorite questions id within user and store and store user id's withing question. During favorite operation you will need insert data in two places (user, question) but you will be able to retrieve quick user/question favorites back.

BTW: If you will use lucene with mongodb you will run into problems with relevance loading from mongodb.

If you need real full text search you can try [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/). It also great nosql database and it natively support Lucene syntax.

**Edit:**

When you designing site like SO keep in the mind:

1. denormalization
2. async request processing
3. background jobs

Comment: thanks - could you explain a bit about the problems that I'll run into with mongo + lucene ?

Comment: @Amila: Yes, if lucene will return to you ids of some entity in relevant order you will not be able to load this data from mongodb in relevant order($in). But you can load data from the mongodb by id's returned from lucene and then restore relevance on client side.

Comment: It won't be a problem. I'm thinking of storing everything needed to display a search result (url,title,user name) in the lucene itself. So I don't have to fetch them from the db again

Answer (score 1):

Have a separate collection for UserFavories is better approach. Because size of the favorites is unknown at any time, and its keep on growing

```
       UserFavories
                -UserID (BSON Objectid)
                - id of the user who posted
                - Name of the user who posted
                - Name of the question
                - Question id
                - url to the question
```

We think storing Userid, Question Id is enough to find the favorites most of the time.  But in non sql, its better to store the very relevant info along with the ids (avoid joins). In this case you store id  & name of the user who posted the question and name,id & url of the question, so you easily display the favorites by just querying this doc alone, like this

[image]

its not an exact way of doing this, but it ll give you an idea..

Comment: disclaimer, I'm really not knowledgeable in docDb, just very interested by it. 
I agree this is probably the correct approach when thinking about performance/ease of use. But aren't you able to achieve this by adding a map reduce index, instead of a whole new collection, where you would add stuff manually?

Comment: @Stephane, Yes you could do that with map/reduce, but why do we need to go for map/reduce since we can do this in a simple way. Map/reduce is better if you wanted to do large operations, but here this is a simple store & retrieval. Use Map/Reduce when there is no other simple way..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the number of favorite flags for each question, you should probably store them with the question to avoid searching through the user database.

Comment: thanks - but to select the favorites of user x it has to scan all the questions - or am I missing something ? Can an Index on the userId list can dramatically improve the performace ?

Comment: @Amila that is correct. I assume that questions are viewed more often than user profiles, according to my own usage profile of stackoverflow.com. An index might help, but you have to measure to be sure. You could also denormalize your data and store both favorites per questions and favorites per user. You could also use Lucene.